# Passed $_POST[] determined by using loop

Tags: php, mysql

My index.php page has several submits within a form which has method post and action referencing another PHP page. For ease of example, let's say there is submit='a1' and submit='a2'.

When the `$__POST` variable is sent from the submit button, I want the new PHP page to select which `$__POST` variable was sent. I have the query and display script made already and it works fine for one `$__POST` if i use `if(isset($__POST['a1']))`, for example. And I can iterate the MySQL query and use `if()` statements for each category i.e.. 'a1', 'a2'...

What I want to do is iterate within a loop because the MySQL query is the same for each category, with the exception of the `WHERE` statement which identifies category fields in my database according to a change in category number. For instance, category 'a1' uses same `mysqlquery` as 'a2', only difference being: ( `WHERE post_id = '1'` for 'a1' and `WHERE post_id = '2'` for 'a2'.)

The code is immaterial..it already works. I just need to determine which post variable was sent to the page so I can iterate the MySQL query from each corresponding `post_id`...I suspect OO programming would help here, but I am curious if I need it or not.

Comment: PDO parametized queries would REALLY help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you do something like:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++)
 {
   if(isset($_POST['a'.$i])) {
   //Do something
 }
}
```